# Azure Data Studio Not Showing SQL Pool Tables

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, azure-data-studio, azure-synapse

I'm trying to access data on a SQL Server with Azure Data Studio. When connecting to the server it shows a SQL Database and a SQL Pool under Databases. I can see and interact with the Tables of the SQL Database but not with the SQL Pool.

When I use the same connection in SQL Server Management Studio all tables are visible for the SQL Pool.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong in Azure Data Studio?

[image]

Comment: Are you using temporal tables?

Comment: Yes, these are temporal tables. But today it works!
What I have done different is, that I resumed the SQL Pool before I connected to the server. Yesterday I did it the other way around and a simple refresh was apparently not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now.
It seems one has to be careful in which order to resume the SQL Pool (this one is paused most of the time) and connect to the SQL Server.
So first resuming the SQL Pool and then connecting to the server seems to have done it.